# Uniformly continuous and uniformly convergent

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm studying the existence of solutions to differential equations.
Consider the initial value problem
$$x'=f(t,x), ~x(a)=b,~ f:D \subset\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$$
Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S \subset D$ and $\phi_k(t)$ converges uniformly to $\phi(t)$.
In the  proof, I don't know why
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_a^tf(s,\phi_k(s))ds=\int_a^tf(s,\phi(s))ds.$$

I want to ask what's the theorem used here?
Thank you!

Comment: No theorem is required. Just apply the definitions.

Comment: As a general idiom, limit assertions tend to be easier when "all the variable stuff is moved to one side." Here we're led to show the magnitude of the difference$$\biggl\|\int_{a}^{t}\bigl[f(s,\phi_k(s))-f(s,\phi(s))\bigr]\,ds\biggr\|$$can be made arbitrarily small. Use the triangle inequality for integrals, then uniform continuity of $f$, and finally uniform convergence of $(\phi_k)\to\phi$ to write out the necessary $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ details.

Comment: Oh, I see.
Thanks for your response!